# Swift - Remove double optional string from dictionary

Tags: swift, swift2

This is breaking my head.

I have one dictionary:

```
var formSearchValues : Dictionary<String, Any?>
```

Then I call a function to send to server some data and for that I need to create extra dictionary for the params.

```
let lastName = String(formSearchValues["lastname"])
let firstName = String(formSearchValues["firstname"])

searchProvider(lastName, firstName: firstName)
```

Then I have my function searchProvider:

```
func searchProvider(lastName: String, firstName : String){

let params = [
            "lastname": fathersLast == "" ? NSNull() : fathersLast,
            "firstname": NSNull(),
            "email" : state.userEmail,
            "male": false,
            "female": false,
            "taxid": NSNull(),
            ] as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

           // print params
           print(params)

           // make call to server

}
```

When I print my params I see:

```
"lastname": Optional(Optional("Smith"))
```

And of course on my server the search won't work because of that.

> Any clue on how to remove this annoying Optional strings?

Comment: With the usual `if let` or `guard let` or any of the many ways to safely unwrap Optionals. Read [this chapter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330) in the manual.

Comment: Do I have to do that for every item in my dictionary? That's crazy :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As *@Eric D* suggested, the problem is related to how you extract values from your dictionary.

### Solution 1

Replace this

```
let lastName = String(formSearchValues["lastname"])
let firstName = String(formSearchValues["firstname"])
```

with this

```
guard let
        firstName = formSearchValues["firstName"] as? String,
        lastName = formSearchValues["lastName"] as? String
        else { fatalError() }
```

> Please note that this code will crash your app if valid Strings are not found for the `firstName` and `lastName`.
>   Alternatively you can replace the `fatalError()` instruction with another flow-breaking instruction like `return`.

### Solution 2

If you have a default value to use when `firstName` or `lastName` are 'nils' then here's the code

```
let defaultValue = ""
let firstName = (formSearchValues["firstName"] as? String) ?? defaultValue
let lastName = (formSearchValues["lastName"] as? String) ?? defaultValue
```

Comment: Amazing... the solution number 2 was the right for me because on the params dictionary  I have: "lastname": fathersLast == "" ? NSNull() : fathersLast,

Answer (score 0):

A Dictionary always returns an Optional.

Your issue is that in your dictionary, the values are also Optionals:

```
var formSearchValues : Dictionary<String, Any?> 
                                             ^ value is an Optional
```

That makes the output a double Optional (nested Optionals), which is not convenient, for sure.

I suggest you refactor to not have Optionals as values in the first place, or if you have to keep this way, then yes, you have to unwrap each value twice.

Answer (score 0):

If "lastname" is guaranteed to be in the dictionary and have an associated value, you can do the following:

```
let lastName = String(formSearchValues["lastname"]!!)
```

This will unwrap the optionals and leave you with a string.

*Don't do this if either the key might not always be there or it might not have a value.*  In this case use something like [appzYourLife's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38375341/1245027).

Comment: Seems to work when the key has some value but if that is nil then I get the error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: That is the expected behaviour.